# Find video content option using Youtube Data API

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find what content option a video is part of.
Youtube has 3 content options:

- Explore
- Explore More
- Most of Youtube

As explained in this link: [A new choice for parents of tweens and teens on YouTube](https://blog.youtube/news-and-events/supervised-experiences-for-families-on-youtube/).

Using the youtube data api and sending the id of a youtube video, how do I find the content option of that video?

API link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%2Cid%2Clocalizations%2Cplayer%2Csnippet%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus%2CtopicDetails%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22AE4tZ18sHeU%22%5D%7D